# express + nginx : User dashboard shows wrong users' data

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

I am working on an node-express application with mongodb. I am using reverse proxy with nginx which then takes the request to express app listening on port 3000.

My users are compaining that when they log in some other users' information is displayed. 
Though it happens very rare, it is a serious issue. 
I can't figure out what could go wrong. This is the code I am using to log the user in :

```
 var captchaResponse = req.body['g-recaptcha-response'];
        var remoteAddress = req.connection.remoteAddress;

        var test = verifyCaptcha(captchaResponse, remoteAddress);
        test().then(function (response) {

            if (!response.success) {
                email = req.body.email;
                User.findOne({ 'email': email, 'verified': true }, function (err, user) {

                    if (!err && !user) {

                        res.status(422).render("login.ejs", { message: "Please Verify your email." });
                        return;
                    }
                    else {
                        if (!user.validPassword(req.body.password)) {
                            res.status(422).render("login.ejs", { message: "Invalid credentials" });
                            return;
                        }
                        else {
                            var token = jwt.sign({ id: user._id }, config.secret, {
                                expiresIn: 900 // expires in 24 hours
                            });
                            res.cookie('email', email, { httpOnly: true });
                            res.cookie('access_token', token, { httpOnly: true }).status(301).redirect('/home');

                        }
                    }

                });
            }
            else {
                res.render("login.ejs", { message: response.responseDesc });
            }
        });
```

Comment: Would nginx have  some kind of cache?

Comment: though I didn't do anything such. Would it be meaningful to show you the nginx configuration code?

Comment: Of course, but you could always "find /etc/nginx -type f | xargs grep -i cache".

Comment: `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default: proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;` This is the result of grep.

Comment: https://medium.com/javascript-scene/introduction-to-node-express-90c431f9e6fd warns for that problem, claiming using res.locals is necessary to keep things private.

Comment: I added a line `add_header Cache control 'no-cache'` That did not solve the problem. What else could be the reason?

Comment: That header may be respected by your clients (it's addressed to them), but it will in no way influence node-express's caching.